# How to center View inside layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layout-gravity

I have to build layout like at the picture below.
The main task is to center the text.

[image]

I use this xml for implementing layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/author">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_overlay"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/previous"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But it works incorrectly.
 
I need to center `TextView` `android:id="@+id/author"` inside `LinearLayout` `android:id="@+id/ll"`. But it is centered in the parent `RelativeLayout` `android:id="@+id/main_layout"`.
I use `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` for `LinearLayout` `android:id="@+id/ll"`.
How can my Layout fill not the parent but only remaining space?
Give an example of its implementation, if anyone come to similar issue.

**EDIT:** Now I have wrong centered text like at the picture below now.
[image]

At this moment, I think the best solution is to use android:layout_weight.
But when the ads are not shown - the proportions are violated.

Comment: sorry, check my answer one more time.

Comment: Even when use `android: layout_above: "@ + id / footer_layout"` still `LinearLayout` `android: id = "@ + id / ll"` is stretched to full parent `RelativeLayout`

Comment: I've just test it and it works just fine, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/author"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_overlay"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great answer! It really centered.
I missed something the first time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

in the linearlayout, add the property: gravity="center_horizontal"
and in the textview add the property: layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

Comment: I tried to do so. But it is centered in the parent RelativeLayout. I want Layout fill not the parent but only remaining space above footer_layout. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: try adding weight to the components!

Comment: A good suggestion.
I tried it. But when the ads are not shown - the proportions are violated.

Answer (score 2):

add gravity to your textview. find the following code

```
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="hiiiiiiiiiii"/>
```

this will provide your textview in the centre of the layout...

Answer (score 0):

Change your text view layout like following :

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/author">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `layout_centerInParent = true`

Comment: I added the picture for clarification.